# Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work? Please see screenshot

Tags: mysql, date

[image]

I believe my date format is correct. 
This happened with the rest of the tables as well :(

Comment: Use `' 2009-07-11'` as date and don't forget the quotes around the date.

Comment: Please **do not post pictures of code** but post code as text instead. And use `'2009-07-11'`. (incl. ticks).

Comment: tried this as well
INSERT INTO Curator (CuratorName, CPhoneNumber, EmpolymentDate) VALUES (AnneGreenland, 322554897, 2009-07-11);

Comment: should be `'2009-07-11'` not `2009-07-11`

Comment: I have done this now:
INSERT INTO Curator (CuratorName, CPhoneNumber, EmploymentDate) VALUES (AnneGreenland, 322554897, ‘2009-07-11’);

Comment: it now says: Unknown column AnneGreenland in field list

Comment: now you are missing quote @ `'AnneGreenland'` check @Vincent's answer

Comment: @PerlDog sorry will not post screen shots again, it's just so much easier and quicker...

Comment: well, I have done this now and it works!!! Thank you 
INSERT INTO Curator (CuratorName, CPhoneNumber, EmploymentDate) VALUES (“AnneGreenland”, 322554897, “2009-07-11”);

Answer (score 3):

You just need to surround your first attribute with simple quotes, because it is a varchar

And for the date: you also need to surround it with quotes, and it must follow `'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'` format (dashes, not dots):

```
INSERT INTO Curator VALUES ('AnneGreenland', 322554897, '2009-07-11');
```

Answer (score 1):

Varchar and date are string. So, use them within " symbol.

INSERT INTO Curator (CuratorName, CPhoneNumber, EmpolymentDate) VALUES ("AnneGreenland", 322554897, "2009-07-11");

Comment: Yep but be careful: **standard SQL only support simple quotes as string delimiters!!!** It maybe works with MySQL, but it is a mistake, in this case, so you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the double quotes for each string and date value. What is more there is other error, the date type need `-` instead of `.`.

You need also to include the column names if you won't insert all columns values.

```
INSERT INTO Curator (CuratorName, CPhoneNumber, EmpolymentDate)
       VALUES ("AnneGreenland", 322554897, "2009-07-11");
```

But in your case you can just do the next:

```
INSERT INTO Curator VALUES ("AnneGreenland", 322554897, "2009-07-11");
```

I hope that helps :D

Comment: It's OK, but be careful : double quotes is deprecated for surrounding strings, because  in SQL specifications, strings are surrounded with simple quotes. It works with MySQL, but can throw a syntax error with others database managing tools

Comment: @Vincent you are right but I'm referring just to mysql syntax.

Answer (score -2):

You have to name the columns you're setting.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

Comment: You don't have to. You should though.

Comment: Only if you have auto-generated or default values (ex; ID: auto-increments). When you set all of them, you don't need to

Comment: I have done this now: INSERT INTO Curator (CuratorName, CPhoneNumber, EmploymentDate) VALUES (AnneGreenland, 322554897, ‘2009-07-11’);

Comment: it now says: Unknown column AnneGreenland in field list

Comment: I have CuratorName as varchar(50)

Comment: @Almaron, Vincent is right. Not necessary if you're not setting all values.

Comment: @ElenaT see my answer, you need to surround strings with simple quotes ;)